# Android's count field in BaseColums

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have been working with a database defining the columns with the help of the BaseColumns interface. its pretty standard implementation. but i am curious about the Count constant mentioned there. i am using a content provider for the queries so a custom count query isn't really an option. so far i have been using the query count with a projection of only the ids, seemed more lighweight that way.

what is the `_COUNT` field in BaseColumns used for? i am assuming its for a count of rows. 
  how do i build the scheme with that field?
  how do i query the count?